# macOS app on Catalina through Xcode receives "TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen"

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-catalina

With Catalina out, I have took time to update and tried to run my app but I am facing a weird issue.

My app is monitoring key events therefore needing the new authorization to monitor inputs.

If I run through the signed bundle, I do get the warning telling me to turn it on in the system preferences which I do. It then works fine.

If I do the same running through Xcode or through Iterm2, I always have the "TCC deny IOHIDDeviceOpen". I have tried to authorize products of the build but it does not change anything.

Anyone with an idea ?

Answer (score 3):

If that doesn't work, make sure your terminal program (e.g. iTerm.app) is also checked in the "Input Monitoring" permissions.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. I found that removing all entries for my app from System Preferences->Security & Privacy->Input Monitoring and then re-running under Xcode worked. It is almost like Catalina recognises the app as one in the store and doesn't ask about turning support on but then sees it as a different app when it actually comes to opening devices

Comment: how to avoid this? everytime i build i have to provide the permission again, also it points to installed version or release version. I have to delete the installed version and give permission to right development build. everytime doing this is frustrating.